# Subgroups as isotropy subgroups and regular orbits on tuples

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, finite-groups, characters

> Is there some natural or character-theoretic description of the minimum value of *d* such that *G* has a regular orbit on *Ω<sup>d</sup>*, where *G* is a finite group acting faithfully on a set *Ω*?

**Motivation**:
In some cases, there are so many kinds of orbits of *G* on *Ω* that every subgroup of *G* appears as a point-stabilizer.  However, these actions are quite rare, even in the case of a [point group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_group) of a group of Euclidean isometries. (The only such actions in 2D are C<sub>1</sub>, D<sub>1</sub>, and C<sub>*p*</sub> for primes *p*.  This follows because rotation subgroups only stabilize the origin.)

[[image: subgroups as isotropy subgroups]  (example for D4 by Bill Cook)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76255/show-every-subgroup-of-d4-can-be-regarded-as-an-isotropy-group-for-a-suitable-ac/76423#76423).

If we allow the group to act on subsets too, then we may have better luck.  See for instance, the [lovely example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76255/show-every-subgroup-of-d4-can-be-regarded-as-an-isotropy-group-for-a-suitable-ac/76423#76423) of dihedral groups and cyclic groups acting naturally on the Euclidean plane as Rosette groups.  Here one can take various natural subsets of the polygon to get all subgroups.

In general a finite point group of a group of Euclidean isometries has a regular orbit, and the blocks of that orbit suffice to specify all subgroups (there is a 1-1 correspondence between subgroups containing a point stabilizer and blocks of the orbit given, and this correspondence is given by the set-wise stabilizer).  This is true more generally for small groups acting on large vector spaces (if *V* is *n*-dimensional over *K* and |*G*|−1 < 1+|*K*|+…+|*K*|<sup>*n*−1</sup>, then *G* has a regular orbit on *V* in any faithful, linear action of *G* on *V*; in particular finite groups acting on infinite vector spaces are fine).

However, determining which medium-ish linear groups over medium-ish vector spaces have regular orbits is really hard, as far as I know.  I wondered if it was much easier if we allowed one to replace *V* by *V* ⊕ *V*.  Certainly we can replace *V* by *V<sup>V</sup>* (taking *d*=|*V*|), but that is a bit extreme.

> Is there some reasonable value of *d* that can be read from the permutation character of *G* on *Ω*, from the (Brauer) character of *G* on *V*, or some other natural invariant of the action of *G* on *Ω*?

An expression for the minimum would be nice, but even some decent bound on *d* in terms of invariants would be fine.

To identify Galois groups, one also looks for certain invariants for polynomials, and I believe what I am asking is relevant to how complicated such invariants need to be.  GAP for instance takes *d* ≤ 5, I think (and used to take *d* ≤ 3, I think), but it has lots of "backup" routines to identify various other subgroups, possibly for efficiency, but possibly because one cannot choose *d* that small in general.

Comment: Jack, this seems to be an excellent research question, maybe you should post it on http://mathoverflow.net/ too. Have you contacted Marty Isaacs on this? He is on this StackExchange.

Comment: Very nice question, Did you reach any conclusion ?

Answer (score 1):

This has been open for nearly nine years and is the top-rated unanswered question on Group Theory. So it deserves an answer, even though the questioner appears to no longer come round these parts.

First, something easy. Let $V$ be a $kG$-module, which we will assume is faithful.

Lemma: if $G$ possesses at most $m$ subgroups of prime order, and $|k|\geq m$ then $G$ has a regular orbit on $V$.

The proof is clear: each element of prime order centralizes a proper subspace of $V$. Since $V$ is not the union of $m$ proper subspaces, there is a point $x$ not centralized by any element of order $p$. Thus $x$ lies in a regular orbit. (You can obviously do much better than $m$ here, but this is the easiest to state.)

This deals with $k$ of characteristic $0$, of course. The best results are when $\gcd(|G|,|k|)=1$. Here we use a result of Halasi--Podoski from *Every coprime linear group admits a base of size two*. This states that any faithful module has base size $2$, i.e., there exist two points, $x,y\in V$, such that $C_G(x)\cap C_G(y)=1$. Thus if $W$ is a faithful $kG$-module and $W\oplus W$ is a submodule of $V$ then $G$ has a regular orbit on $W\oplus W\leq V$.

Thus if $V$ is a faithful $kG$-module then $V\otimes V$ contains two non-isomorphic faithful modules, namely $\Lambda^2(V)$ and $S^2(V)$. The tensor product of the two contains two copies of $\Lambda^2(V)\otimes S^2(V)$, so there is always a regular orbit in $V^{\otimes 4}$.

If $V$ is a permutation module then $V=1\oplus W$, and $W\oplus W\leq V\otimes V$. Hence there is a regular orbit in $V^{\otimes 2}$. This of course generalizes to $V$ an arbitrary sum of modules, but we have to be a little careful to make sure that $V\otimes V$ is faithful.

I would guess that even when $V$ is simple that $G$ has a regular orbit on $V\otimes V$, but this has not been proved, as far as I know.

---

Having dealt with the coprime case, we look at the general case. Here the base size can be greater than $2$. Some recent papers of Melissa Lee give bounds on base sizes for quasisimple groups, but as far as I know this looks quite hard. Note that a result of Auslander--Carlson states that if $V$ is absolutely indecomposable and of dimension divisible by $p=\mathrm{char}(k)$, then $V\otimes V^*\otimes V$ contains $V\oplus V$. This means that in that situation we do obtain two summands isomorphic to $V$ in $V^{\otimes 3}$, whenever $V$ is self-dual. Thus we may exploit base sizes again. In general, of course, knowing composition factors of $V^{\otimes n}$ doesn't help you too much, because you need composition factors of the socle to guarantee that you achieve a regular orbit.

My guess would be that if $V=W_1\oplus W_2$ and each $W_i$ has base size $2$, then with few exceptions $V$ possesses a regular orbit.