# Why are they called orbits?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, group-actions

When we study actions in group theory, we consider sets of the form
$$\text{Orb}_G(x)=\{gx\mid g\in G\} $$
that are called orbits. Although, the only reason I find convincing for that name is that in some sense the action of group over a set can be viewed as a dynamical system and thus the name orbit has the usual physical "interpretation" and justification. Is this explanation correct or only a funny coincidence? In the second case, which is the origin of the term?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76255/show-every-subgroup-of-d4-can-be-regarded-as-an-isotropy-group-for-a-suitable-ac/76423#76423 my picture might help you to see why we use the term "orbits". What better word could we use when dealing with groups of symmetries? :)

Comment: The dynamical system interpretation is also the most convincing motivation I can think of, but I don't know anything about the history of the term.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the group action allowing you to move from one point to the next. In a "physical" sense, we are looking at where we can go in the set so we are looking at what elements we pass through on our way through.